# Family tree with multiple spouse relation

Tags: css, reactjs, treeview, nodes, family-tree

Currently, I'm trying to have a family tree that will have
Multiple Spouses. (When it is going more than two spouses, the link is not going
separately),
Son and daughter relationship also there
I am doing this done in React.js.

The relation I am getting,but i want to different line for spouse:

[image]

```
<ReactFamilyTree
            nodes={nodes as Node[]}
            rootId={rootId}
            width={WIDTH}
            height={HEIGHT}
            className={styles.tree}
            renderNode={(node: ExtNode) => (
              <FamilyNode
                key={node.id}
                node={node}
                isRoot={node.id === rootId}
                onSubClick={setRootId}
                style={{
                  width: WIDTH,
                  height: HEIGHT,
                  transform: `translate(${node.left * (WIDTH / 2)}px, ${node.top * (HEIGHT / 2)}px)`,
                }}
              />
            )}
          />
```